# Direct Sum: Stone

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Problem**

Given Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_\alpha$.

Consider Hamiltonians:
$$H_\alpha:\mathcal{D}H_\alpha\subseteq\mathcal{H}_\alpha\to\mathcal{H}_\alpha:\quad H_\alpha=H_\alpha^*$$
And their evolution:
$$U_\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}_\alpha):\quad U_\alpha(t):=e^{-itH_\alpha}$$

Regard the domain:
$$\mathcal{D}H:=\left\{\varphi\in\bigoplus_\alpha\mathcal{H}_\alpha:\sum_\alpha\|H_\alpha\varphi_\alpha\|_\alpha^2<\infty\right\}$$

Then for their sum:
$$H=\bigoplus_\alpha H_\alpha\implies U=\bigoplus_\alpha U_\alpha$$

How can I check this?

**Attempt**

It is a group:
$$U(s+t)=U(t)U(s)\quad U(0)=1$$

For strong continuity:
$$\|U(\Delta t)\varphi-\varphi\|^2=\ldots=\sum_\alpha\|U_\alpha(\Delta t)\varphi_\alpha-\varphi_\alpha\|_\alpha^2$$

And strong derivative:
$$\left\|\tfrac{1}{\Delta t}\{U(\Delta t)-1\}\varphi-H\varphi\right\|^2=\ldots=\sum_\alpha\left\|\tfrac{1}{\Delta t}\{U_\alpha(\Delta t)-1_\alpha\}\varphi-H_\alpha\varphi_\alpha\right\|_\alpha^2$$

How can they vanish?

Comment: Please state precisely your definition of $H$. What is the domain of $H$, for example?

Comment: @TrialAndError: You mean e.g. its domain?

Comment: Given the domains of $H_{\alpha}$, what is the domain of $H$?

Comment: @TrialAndError: I added its domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a clear domain definition, and $\|\frac{1}{\Delta t}\{U_{\alpha}(\Delta t)-1_\alpha\}\varphi_{\alpha}-H_{\alpha}\varphi_{\alpha}\|=\|\frac{1}{\Delta t}\int_{0}^{\Delta t}(U_{\alpha}(t)-1_\alpha)H_{\alpha}\varphi_\alpha dt\|$, can you now better establish convergence?

Comment: So exploiting mean-value theorem?

Comment: I assume you mean applied to $\frac{1}{\Delta t}\int_{0}^{\Delta t}\|U_{\alpha}(t)-I)H_{\alpha}x\|dt$. Yes. And you have a uniform bound on the coordinates in terms of $\|H_{\alpha}x\|$, too.

Comment: Hence I can apply dominated convergence on the sum?

Comment: Moreover that gives continuity of the unitary group on a dense set of elements. That proves also strong continuity, right?

Comment: Especially that proves that the sum is selfadjont again?

Comment: @Freeze_S  : I think that's right. You can definitely see the $\mathcal{D}(H)$ is contained in the domain of the generator by the above argument, and I think you can see the opposite inclusion without much effort. So, yes, the generator is then selfadjoint.